# Select a unique names from Users that have more than 3 Articles. Spring Data, H2

Tags: spring-boot, select, spring-data-jpa, h2

I use: Spring Boot, Spring Data, and  H2 (in-memory) DataBase.

DB TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    age  INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE article
(
    id      INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text    TEXT                                            NOT NULL,
    color   ENUM ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink') NOT NULL,
    user_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

In ArticleRepository exploited such query: 
**SELECT u.name, a.user_id, count(*) FROM user AS u INNER JOIN article AS a ON u.id = a.user_id GROUP BY a.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;**

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Integer> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT u.name, a.user_id, count(*) FROM user AS u INNER JOIN article AS a ON u.id = a.user_id GROUP BY a.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 3", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Article> findUserNamesByArticlesCountMoreThan();
}
```

**After request I receive the error:**

*In Postman:*

> "error": "Internal Server Error", "message": "could not execute query;
>   SQL [SELECT u.name, a.user_id, count(text) FROM user AS u INNER JOIN
>   article AS a ON u.id = a.user_id GROUP BY a.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >
>   3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not execute query",

*In IntelliJ Idea:*

> 02:54:24.681 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL
>   Error: 42122, SQLState: 42S22 02:54:24.681 [http-nio-9090-exec-1]
>   ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Column "id" not found [42122-197]
>   02:54:24.703 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] ERROR [dispatcherServlet] -
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not execute query; SQL [SELECT u.name, a.user_id, count(text) FROM
>   user AS u INNER JOIN article AS a ON u.id = a.user_id GROUP BY
>   a.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 3]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]
>   with root cause org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "id" not found
>   [42122-197]   at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getColumnIndex(JdbcResultSet.java:3148)     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:3247)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:346)..............

**Help me to resolve this problem, and find a mistake.**

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
  private String text;
  @Column(name = "color", nullable = false, unique = true)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Color color;
  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
  private User user;
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "articles")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
  private Integer age;
  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {

  private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

  @Autowired
  public ArticleService(ArticleRepository articleRepository) {
    this.articleRepository = articleRepository;
  }

public List<Article> findAllUserNamesByArticlesMoreThan() {
  return articleRepository.findUserNamesByArticlesCountMoreThan(); }}
```

ArticleDtoService:

```
@Service
public class ArticleDtoService {

  private ArticleService articleService;

@Autowired
public ArticleDtoService(ArticleService articleService) {
  this.articleService = articleService;
}

public ResponseEntity<List<ArticleDto>> getAllUserNamesByArticlesMoreThan() {
  List<Article> articles = articleService.findAllUserNamesByArticlesMoreThan();
  Link link = linkTo(methodOn(ArticleController.class).getAllUserNamesListByArticlesMoreThan()).withSelfRel();
  return new ResponseEntity<>(createArticleDtoList(articles, link), HttpStatus.OK); }}
```

ArticleController:

```
@RestController
public class ArticleController {

  private final ArticleDtoService articleDtoService;

  @Autowired
  public ArticleController(ArticleDtoService articleDtoService) {
    this.articleDtoService = articleDtoService;
  }

@GetMapping(value = "/api/articles/count")
public ResponseEntity<List<ArticleDto>> getAllUserNamesListByArticlesMoreThan() {
  return articleDtoService.getAllUserNamesByArticlesMoreThan(); }}
```

ArticleDto:

```
public class ArticleDto extends ResourceSupport {

  public Article article;

  public ArticleDto(Article article, Link selfLink) {
    this.article = article;
    add(selfLink); }}
```

Comment: `with root cause org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "id" not found`